# SpringBoot 3 AOT/GraalVM/Native: Build native binary from Windows to run on Linux

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Small question regarding SpringBoot 3 and the new AOT Native binary with GraalVM please.

I am building my java SpringBoot 3 app on a Windows machine (no judging please!) in order to `scp` the binary on a Linux host.

I followed the GraalVM installation guide and could install GraalVM, generate the binary image. The binary runs fine on my Windows machine.

Actually, I had another Linux machine, where I installed GraalVM, generated the binary image. The binary image would run fine on the Linux machine.

However, this Linux machine to "build the binary" is not available anymore.

Therefore, I am building the native image using Windows, hoping it can run on Linux (concept which works with a plain old .jar)

Unfortunately, the Linux machine cannot run the binary (probably because it was built on Windows).

May I ask how can I achieve building the SpringBoot 3 native binary from my Windows machine, and then be able to run it on any other Linux machine please?

(If possible, with something simple, without having me to install a dual boot windows/ubuntu, or having to pay a cloud provider CI/CD pipeline)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are stuck with some dated Windows desktop with no means of updating to release from ~2019 release, you should go with [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) or [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/) and replicate your missing Linux machine.